# What time format is this? Is it UNIX?

Tags: time

What time format is this: 131870287476928345 ? I tried converting it from UNIX but I get back:

Assuming that this timestamp is in microseconds (1/1,000,000 second):
GMT: Saturday, October 15, 2011 6:21:14.769 PM

I should get back something like: Sunday, Nov 18, 2018

Comment: I'm not sure what format it is. It looks much too long to be a Unix timestamp.

Comment: Where did it come from?

Comment: @WaiHaLee from an API, I think they use .net to run the API, it's private

Comment: `DateTime.FromFileTime(131870287476928345)` seems to do the right thing, so this is probably a Win32 `FILETIME` (which has an epoch of January 1, 1601 and a resolution of 100 ns).

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes, it was Win32 Filetime. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that 131870287476928345 is timestamp may be is UnixNano - the number of nanoseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 UTC.

131870287476928345 -> 1974-03-07 13:38:07.476928345 +0700 +07

Comment: In the comments it's stated that it's a [FileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284(v=vs.85).aspx). Plus, the time you get out doesn't agree with the time specified in the question.